# Javascript Templates with Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, templates

I'm experimenting with client side templates and came up with the following concept:

```
<table>
    <tr bind-template="colors,<td style='color:@color'>@name</td>"></tr>
</table>
```

and I have a javascript object as in:

```
var colors = [{name: 'white', color: '#FFFFFF'},{name: 'black', color: '#000000'}];
```

So, from the 'bind-template' attribute, I can get to the actual object "colors", and then the template itself

```
<td style='color:@color'>@name</td>
```

I'm not good at regular expressions but what I came up with the get the folowing:

```
<td style='color:#FFFFFF'>white</td>
<td style='color:#000000'>black</td
```

I simply created a prototype on Array as in:

```
    Array.prototype.HelperResult = function (template, el) {
        var arr = [];
        var result = null;

        $(this).each(function (index, item) {
            result = template;
            for (var o in item) {
                if (template.indexOf('@' + o) >=0)
                {
                    result = result.replace('@' + o, item[o]);
                }
            }
            arr.push(result);
        });

        $(el).append(arr.join(''));
    };
```

To me, this seems a bit clunky but it works. Here is how I call this method:

```
        var templates = $('[bind-template]');

        $(templates).each(function (index) {
            var attr = $(this).attr('bind-template');

            if (attr) {
                var parts = attr.split(',');
                if (parts.length == 2)
                {
                    self[parts[0]].HelperResult(parts[1], this);
                }
            }
        });
```

I'm going to clean this up but what I need help with is coming up with a cleaner way to get the values for @color and @name from the iterations, and I guessing it will be in the way of regular expressions which I don't know too well.

Thanks for any ideas. Once again, all this is just a proof of concept :-)

Thanks all,

Comment: I had to fix a few bugs in the above code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use regexps? Because they're cool? =)

Your code works well, I think there is no reason to change it much.

The only moments I wanna to notice:

1. I do believe there is no reason to call indexOf() before calling replace() - the last one will do the same work for searching occurrence of the text, so you did the work twice.
2. I guess that we should find all occurrences of `@tagname` in the template, for cases like

   `<td id="@name">@name</td>`

So my refactoring would be:

```
-           if (template.indexOf('@' + o) >=0)
-           {
-               result = result.replace('@' + o, item[o]);
-           }

+           result = result.replace('@' + o, item[o], 'g');
```

P.S. But if you wanna do regexp, you may write

```
            result = result.replace(new RegExp('@' + o, 'g'), item[o]);
```

and make your code cooler. ;)

Comment: I hear ya. I took out the indexOf check. I modifed the ResultHelper function to process items using a settimeout as to not stall the UI thread when processing alot of items. It's crazy fast. I'll probably run into performance issues as I progress with this template engine but it;s coming along nicely.